# Using "yield" in a function

Tags: python, generator, yield

I want to generate something like that in a function that receives 1 argument `n` using `yield` to generate:

```
      1
     1+2
    1+2+3
      …
      …
1+2+3+⋯+n−1+n
```

That is my last try:

```
def suite(n):
    total = 0
    for i in n:
        total+=i
        yield total
```

and this is what I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notebook", line 4, in suite
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You should iterate over `range(n)` instead

Answer (score 4):

Your error is here:

```
for i in n:
```

`n` is an integer and not an iterable. Perhaps you wanted to use [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) (Python 2 only) or [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) (recommended on Python 3) here:

```
for i in range(n):
```

Note that this starts iteration at *0*, not 1 (up to and including `n - 1`). You could either use `range(1, n + 1)`, or simply add 1 to your sum:

```
def suite(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(n):
        total += i + 1
        yield total
```

This hasn't really got anything to do with generators; wether or not you used `yield`, trying to loop over a plain `int` object doesn't work either way.

Answer (score 1):

Because your function declaration doesn not correspond with for loop. You cannot iterate over integer, you should use some iterable instead. The simplest way is to use range:

The correct version is:

```
def suite(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(n):
        total += i
        yield total
>>>suite(6)
```

Or, you can do another change to yield sum of some iterable:

```
def suite(iterable):
    total = 0
    for i in iterable:
        total += i
        yield total

>>>suite([1,2,3])
```

Comment: This has little to do with a function declaration. You'd get the same error with that loop outside a function.

Comment: See edited answer. I meant that declaration doesn't correspond with for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) to create an iterator to use in your `for` loop:

```
def suite(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        total+=i
        yield total
```