# randint function not iterating over the list

Tags: python

I have to push some 20000 items in a stack to check the time complexity.
Here's my code

```
from time import time
import random
class Node(object):
def __init__(self, value=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = None
class StackwithNodes(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.top = None
def isEmpty(self):
    return bool(self.top)
def pop(self):
    node = self.top
    if node:
        self.top = node.next
        return node.value
    else:
        raise Exception('Stack is empty.')
def push(self, value):
    node = Node(value)
    node.next = self.top
    self.top = node
def size(self):
    node = self.top
    num_nodes = 1
    if node is None: 
        return 0
    node = node.next
    while node:
        num_nodes =num_nodes+1
        node = node.next
    return num_nodes
def peek(self):
    return self.top.value

def main():
stack = StackwithNodes()
start_time = time()

for i in random.randint(1,2000):
    stack.push(i)
    end_time=time()

end_time=time()
elapsed = end_time-start_time
print "the time for 100000 push operations with node is :",elapsed
print(stack.size())
print(stack.peek())
print(stack.pop())
print(stack.peek())
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

but its showing error as

```
      for i in random.randint(1,2000):
      TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

and someone help me to get rid of this error please I want to analyze the time and space complexity and for less value the time is coming to be 0.0 so I want to test it on large numbers.

Comment: Duplicate, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045392/using-yield-in-a-function/35045413#35045413

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to populate your stack with large data you can use

```
    for i in range(200000):
    stack.push(i)
```

instead of your for loop but this will populate the stack with 200000 numbers from in continuation and if you want to randomize them you can add this

```
    import random
    random.sample(range(30), 200000)
```

where range(30) is that numbers will be from 1 to 30 and 200000 is for number of items

and then you can use for loop to push them in stack as already shown above

Answer (score 0):

random.randint(1,2000) returns a int which is not iterable, use range and xrange to iterate on it.

```
for i in xrange(random.randint(1,2000))  #use range in python3.x
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for i in range(random.randint(1,2000)):
    stack.push(i)
    end_time=time()
```